# Using long polling in servlets

Tags: javascript, servlets, web-applications, long-polling

In a web card game I'm building, I need to update some parts of the application for all users when one user make a change. For example when one user play a card, others should see it. 
I'm using servlets for the server and javascript for the front end. I understand that long polling can be used in servlets. But in a servlets, separate threads are created for each user. They run independently. How do we send responses for each user in the game(each thread) when one user make a change? On the client side, how do we make the client poll for a responses from the servlet? I searched for this and I could not find any good sample code.

Comment: I would suggest using a `setInterval` function to check periodically for new information. Rather than reloading the information each interval you can use a counter to see how many messages are in the current communication and add new information only

Comment: This means I don't have to do anything new on servlet, but send requests from client side periodically? Javascript is sort of asynchronous? So other mechanisms won't be affected by polling?

Comment: well the servlet can hold on to the counter variable so you don't really request all the information (including the one you already have) but only the new messages, so you only need to implement a counting mechanism